# Unfurling two columns in a Pandas dataframe into a list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, networkx

I have two columns in a Pandas dataframe whose values logically follow one another.  See the following:

```
Name                Includes

Account             Product Account
Product Account     Card Account
Card Account        Plastic
Card Account        Token
Token               Token Vault
Account             Savings Account
```

So Account > Product Account > Card Account, etc.  Ultimately I want to create a list of lists where the root ('Account') is the first element of each list.  The output should look like the following:

```
[['Account', 'Product Account', 'Card Account', 'Plastic'],
 ['Account', 'Product Account', 'Card Account', 'Token', 'Token Vault'],
 ['Account', 'Savings Account']]
```

I basically want to find any and all possible paths between the dataframe elements that may exist.  I currently have a code that converts the two dataframe columns into a dictionary structure:

```
def link_hops(dictionary):

    dictionary = dict(df.groupby('Name')['Includes'].apply(set))
    dictionary = {k: list(v) for k, v in dictionary.items()}

    all_values = set(x for xs in dictionary.values() for x in xs)
    refs = all_values & set(dictionary.keys())

    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        for i in range(len(v)):
            if v[i] in refs:
                v[i] = {v[i]: v1 for k1, v1 in dictionary.items() if v[i] == k1}

    dictionary = {k: v for k, v in dictionary.items() if k not in refs}

    return dictionary
```

I get the following:

```
{'Account': ['Savings Account',
            {'Product Account': [{'Card Account': ['Plastic',
            {'Token': ['Token Vault']}]}]}]}
```

This code does the job of defining all of the paths that exist from the root ('Account') to the terminus for each path ('Savings Account', 'Plastic', 'Token Vault'), but I cannot figure out how to convert this into a list format that is scalable.  I have a recursion script which does work on small examples like this, but the actual dataframes I am working with can potentially be hundreds or thousands of levels deep when I convert them into dictionaries via `link_hops`, and easily blow past the recursion limit when I call that script.

I want to know if it is possible to skip the intermediate step of converting my dataframe into a dictionary and directly convert it into a list of lists, or even just use `.map()` or something similar to work on the dataframe directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### #Approach1

Here's one approach, taking each row from the dataframe as a graph edge of a directed graph using `NetworkX` and looking for the [`shortest_path`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path) from `Account` to the different *targets*:

```
import numpy as np
a = df.values
# check correspondence with value in next row and first col
m = np.r_[False, (a[:-1, 1] != a[1:, 0])].cumsum()
# array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
# get indices of where theres is not a correspondence
m_diff = np.r_[m[:-1] != m[1:], True]
# array([False, False,  True, False,  True,  True])
# get targets of all paths
targets = a[m_diff, 1]
# array(['Plastic', 'TokenVault', 'SavingsAccount'], dtype=object)


# define a directed graph using networkx
import networkx as nx
#add edges from the graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Name', target='Includes')
#find all shortest paths from Account to the different found targets
[nx.shortest_path(G, 'Account', target) for target in targets]

[['Account', 'ProductAccount', 'CardAccount', 'Plastic'],
 ['Account', 'ProductAccount', 'CardAccount', 'Token', 'TokenVault'],
 ['Account', 'SavingsAccount']]
```

---

#### #Approach2

Another way to find the graph *end nodes* could be to look at the [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)), and keep those that have a degree of 1:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Name', target='Includes')
[nx.shortest_path(G, 'Account', node) for node, degree in G.degree() if degree==1]

[['Account', 'ProductAccount', 'CardAccount', 'Plastic'],
 ['Account', 'ProductAccount', 'CardAccount', 'Token', 'TokenVault'],
 ['Account', 'SavingsAccount']]
```

---

For a visual understanding of the graph problem being solved:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, scale=20)
nx.draw(G, pos, node_color='lightblue', node_size=500, with_labels=True)
```

[image]

As we can see, by knowing the *sources* and *targets* to look for, by using `nx.shortest_path` we can obtain the path between `Account` and the obtained targets

Comment: amazing, I thought about this for ten minutes and gave up. Is there a certain name for this sort of problem where I can read up on?

Comment: You could read on [Graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) if that helps. There's also a link in the answer on shortest paths @Datanovice

Comment: Awesome, I think this is what I am looking for.  Can this code be configured to handle multiple roots?  If I had something in addition to 'Account' as a root, for example.

Comment: Yes @njrob you could extend the list comprehension to check on several root nodes